# prevent select element from triggering hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html

I have a select box within a hyperlink. Unfortunately, It has to be this way due to some formatting constraints.

My code is as follows...

```
<a id="<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>" class="radio-picture-meats" href="javascript:set_radio('<? echo $rows['itemname']; ?>');">

<span class="item_label"><? echo $rows['displayname'];?></span>

<span class="item_label_price">Per Pound<BR>$<? echo $rows['price'];?></span>

<img class="box" src="<? echo $rows['imagepath']; ?>" width="300px" height="215px"/>

<select class="weight">
<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
<option value="1/2 Pound">1/2 Pound</option>
<option value="1 Pound">1 Pound</option>
</select>   

</a>
```

Is there a way to prevent the select box from triggering the parent hyperlink?

Thank You

Here is a fiddle. You will notice when the dropdown select box is click, it triggers the HREF link. I would like to prevent that from happening.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bhnwjpgy/4/)

This is the solution that worked. If I click the google image, the hyperlink opens, if I click the dropdown box, it doesn't. Perfect

$('.weight').click(function(){ return false; });

[Solution FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bhnwjpgy/8/)

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: Sure. I just added a fiddle.

Comment: It was actually the class "weight" that needed to be the element, but I was able to figure that out based on the answers. Thank You!!!

Comment: Yeah selector can be anything depending on need but important point is to `return false`

Comment: Use stop propagation for class "weight"

Comment: @Jack `return false` is equivalent to `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Thanks, @Pixel No. But as my point of view if the user can do something with the select box but parent styling is disturbing we ll use, so he can do something after stopPropagation(). If we use return he can't continue after words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return false from link click event

```
$({selector_for_anchor}).click(function(){ return false; });
```

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhnwjpgy/5/)

Add a javascript as follows

```
$('#a-link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

where `a-link` is the id of the `<a>`.

Read more about `preventDefault()` in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Alternatively, you can return `false` from the click event which does the same functionality as the `preventDefault()`. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhnwjpgy/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to prevent only on above a tag then please try with php+jquery combine to prevent click on a tag.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#<?php echo $rows['itemname']; ?>").click(function(e){

           //to prevent click   
           return false;

      });
  </script>
```